# WSL Ubuntu keeps disconnecting from internet

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, internet

My WSL instance (version 2.0.14.0) is having internet connectivity issues. My machine is connected to the internet as I'm able to surf the web outside of WSL. The only temporary solution I've found is to run `wsl --shutdown` in a command prompt each time this happens. Upon restart it can connect again. I am looking for a more permanent solution. The error messages is "Temporary failure in name resolution" whenever I try to ping a website, or pull from GitHub. Here is my resolv.conf

```
# resolv.conf
nameserver 172.18.176.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

I also edited the wsl.conf to stop regenerating this file thinking this would solve things, but the issue persists.

```
# wsl.conf
[boot]
systemd=true
[network]
generateResolvConf = false
```

Comment: Welcome!  Can you [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/771822/edit) your question to include your WSL version (`wsl.exe --version`)?  If `wsl.exe --version` simply returns the help, you are on an older version of WSL and may want to upgrade by installing from the Microsoft Store.

Comment: Read the comment in the first line carefully. You need to edit /etc/wsl.conf.

Comment: @reinierpost thank you - I edited the correct file. I then shut down wsl and restarted it, and not resolv.conf disappeared. Made my own using nano and just added those 2 nameserver lines - seems to be working for now.

Comment: The issue still persists